# Multiple website redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am looking to redirect and old website to a new one, but we want to do it in 2 parts;

**We want to redirect the whole blog to the new blog page**

http://www.websiteA.com/news

http://www.websiteA.com/news/post1

http://www.websiteA.com/news/post2 ...

Redirects to;

http://www.websiteB.com/news

**We then want to redirect everything else to the homepage on the new website.**

http://www.websiteA.com/page1

http://www.websiteA.com/page2

http://www.websiteA.com/page3

Redirects to;

http://www.websiteB.com/

How would I do this through the .htaccess?

Comment: This is so low-cost, that asking for the “most efficient way” doesn’t really seem necessary. Am I correct in assuming that this actually means the usual - you have _nothing_ so far, and want us to give you “the solution” …? If so, please go read [ask] first of all.

Comment: Yes I am just looking for a solution, but I have had experience previous where I have been given a long winded solution, hence the "efficient way" I will update

Comment: Main point is, you should show us your attempt (and describe what results you get with that) first of all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these 2 redirect rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# news URIs
RewriteRule ^(news)(?:/.*)?$ /$1? [L,NC,R=301]

# remaining ones
RewriteRule . /? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for this, would this work in redirecting the user to http://www.websiteB.com/ instead of http://www.websiteA.com/

Comment: For that you need to prefix `htttp://websiteB.com` in both targets of `RewriteRule` e.g. `RewriteRule ^(news)(?:/.*)?$ htttp://websiteB.com/$1? [L,NC,R=301]`